# If I convert a personal account into a Facebook Page, what will happen to apps/pages I've created?

Tags: facebook

I need to convert my personal account to a Facebook Page because of the username and some limitations.

What will happen to the Facebook Pages and Facebook Apps I've created using that personal account?

Comment: Aren't Facebook Pages created _in addition_ to your personal account? You use your personal account to administer the Facebook Page.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting it completely wrong! you don't *convert* your personal account to facebook page, you must *make* a facebook page!

In facebook you can have only one personal account, but many pages.

Comment: Not quite. Some famous Facebook users, or people who were users as a _brand_, have been converting to Facebook Pages rather than starting over so that they don't lose all of their followers, etc.